# How to turn off the computer from the GRUB screen in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, reboot

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 with dual boot in a scratch computer (I'm too inexperienced to use anything else). The problem is, every time I try to shutdown from Ubuntu, the computer just reboots and loads the GRUB screen, so that means I can only turn off the computer from Windows 10 and not from Ubuntu.

Can I turn off my PC from the GRUB screen? I do not want to have to turn off from Windows 10 every time I shut down the PC from Ubuntu.

Comment: You can simply power off your computer while it is in the GRUB menu by touching the power button. Unless you have a very old computer, this will trigger an ACPI event that tells the system to shut down and turn off, so it would not be a hard reset anyway. However, the more interesting question is why Ubuntu reboots instead of powering off.

Comment: Indeed. Seems like something's wrong with the way Ubuntu shuts down. 

I verified that mantaining the power button pressed for a couple of seconds powers down the computer without triggering a warning in windows. 
 
Pressing  `c` and then entering `halt` in the prompt also worked for me.

Comment: Actually I meant tapping the power button shortly, not holding it until it cuts the power...

Comment: Tapping the power button shortly is completely ignored from the GRUB screen for some reason.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From [this interesting thread on ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1341990&page=2):

In the GRUB menu, press <kbd>C</kbd> and then enter `halt`.

Also as noted in the link, it is safe to simply press the power button while at the GRUB menu.

Comment: For me I needed to use this to shut down a VM that was stuck in a boot loop and wasn't responding to the hypervisor's shutdown commands.

Answer (score 5):

In the GRUB command line, the equivalent of `poweroff` is `halt`:

```
grub> halt
```

Comment: exactly, this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to shutdown your computer from Ubuntu with one of these commands ? `poweroff` or `sudo shutdown -h now` ?? Your script responsible for shutting your computer off is maybe corrupt. If it is the case, these commands would do the job.

To explicitly answer your actual question (shutting down from the grub), I would hold the power button manually. I do so when I accidentally turn on my computer and finally don't want to :)

Comment: I tried the usual `sudo shutdown` and other variations but it rebooted the computer.
`poweroff` and  takes me to the grub screen instead of shutting down the computer. 
`sudo shutdown -h now` does the same. 
For some reason, the computer turns off and then suddenly turns on again.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this page](https://daulton.ca/2018/08/reboot-and-shutdown-options-grub/), you can do it by adding custom menu options.
`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Add these options:

```
 menuentry "Reboot" {
      reboot
}

menuentry "Shut Down" {
      halt
}
```

Update:
`sudo update-grub`

Reboot:
`reboot`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `halt` in GRUB hangs up the system and nothing happens. So I have to press the power key to poweroff the computer.